Check that (pandas) dataframe has rows without counting them all
I'd like to know if a DataFrame I'm modifying is empty yet. The obvious way would be to compute its length. But that requires counting every row, which is extremely inefficient. Is there a more elegant way?

That said, len(df) is not particularly expensive, the value is cached

You can use the attribute df.empty to check whether it's empty or not:
if df.empty:
    print('DataFrame is empty!')
else:
    print('DataFrame is not empty.')

